# Specify target folder when using batch loader in Oracle Webcenter Content

Tags: oracle, webcenter, oracle-ucm, ecm

I'm using Batch Loader to migrate a large number of files. I'm generating my hda file using a script on the source system. How can I specify the target folder? Everything I've migrated so far has no entry for Folder when I view it's info, and I can't find a way to specify it. Sample of my hda below.

```
# Batch load data for TEST_FILE_3 as jpg
Action=insert
dDocName=TEST_FILE_3_as_jpg
dDocType=Document
dDocTitle=TEST_FILE_3 as jpg title
dDocAuthor=usr_TEST_FILE_3
dSecurityGroup=Public
primaryFile=TEST_FILE_3.jpg
dInDate=01/29/2018
<<EOD>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Native UI, change User Profile Layout to top menus and do a search. When Item is returned, access its Info. When info is displayed, add:  &IsJava=1 to the url and enter.
This shows all metadata field.s Ones you are looking for are one of these: fParentPath, fParentPathLocalized, ownerFilePath, ownerFilePathLocalized

Comment: Thanks Joe, your original answer is actually what helped me the most. I manually added a few files, then archived them and looked at the produced hda files. xCollectionID is what I needed (given that the collection already exists).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps to assist you:

1. Place a file in the folder you want your document to end up in.
2. Find the document info page and append &IsJava to the url. Something like
   http://.../cs/idcplg?IdcService=DOC_INFO&dID=110113&IsJava
3. Examine the output. You will find variables that indicate the path. Their names will differ depending on what components you are using, but a good guess is `fParentPath`
4. Copy name and value to your batch loader file